# How should I setup this type to be intuitive?

Tags: haskell

I have the following types:

```
data Bomb = TimedBomb   { bPos :: Point, bPower :: Float, detTime :: Float }

data Enviro = Enviro { bombs :: [Bomb], stuff :: [Picture]}
```

When the `TimedBomb` timer reaches 0, I need it to explode, damage any enemies within it's blast radius (controlled by `bPower`), and persist for a few seconds to add to the chance that it will cause damage. To do that, I was thinking of creating another object representing an explosion, then check to see if any enemies are within its bounds. The problem is, I can't think of the best set-up to hold explosions that are taking place. I'm using Haskell's Gloss library, so the entirety of what's being drawn needs to be contained within a single "world" object. What I've thought of:

1. I could make an explosion a type of `Bomb`, hold it in `bombs` in the environment, and map over `bombs` when I want to check for collisions. That seems like the simplest route, but it would involve possibly doing checks on non-explosion-`Bombs`, which is inefficient. An explosion isn't really a bomb either; its the end result, so the types don't make intuitive sense.
2. I could make explosions a separate type, then add another field to `Enviro` called explosions of type [Explosion]. That makes more sense, but adds another field to `Enviro`, which already tends to be a cluttered type.
3. I could be thinking of the whole set-up wrong, and there's a third, more sensical way to go about this.

Any thoughts here would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to *store* explosions? Don't they have immediate effect and then go away immediately?

Comment: @raptortech97 I want them to persist for several seconds. I'll clarify that, thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized that I can add a second timer to the bomb that starts when the first one ends, and controls how long the explosion stays active.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Wouldn't adding a second timer violate point number 1 though? If you're going to go that route anyway then I would suggest doing something like `data Bomb = CountingDown {...} | Exploding {...}` to make the phases explicit.

Comment: FYI, this should have been moved to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I figured code review was for long, compilable chunks, while this is a non-complete snippet.

Comment: @Carcigenicate In general: [**stackoverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com) is for when you *have code that doesn't work*, [**codereview.se**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for when you *have code that works* but you want to *make it better*, and [**programmers.se**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is for when you have programming question but *there is no code* you can provide (more abstract topics).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The key to clarity is separation

You should separate the `Bomb`'s constant data from it's mutable state:

```
data Bomb
  = Bomb 
  { bPos    :: Point
  , bPower  :: Float
  , bState  :: BombState
  }
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

data BombState
  = Armed       { detTime :: Float }
  | Discharging { expTime :: Float }
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

data Enviro
  = Enviro
  { bombs :: [Bomb]
  , stuff :: [Picture]
  }
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

isDischarging (Discharging _) = True
isDischarging  _              = False

exploding :: Enviro -> [Bomb]
exploding = filter (isDischarging . bState) . bombs
```

This would allow you to add more states later such as `Disarmed` and `Inert`

```
data BombState
  = Armed       { detTime :: Float }
  | Discharging { expTime :: Float }
  | Disarmed    ( remTime :: Float }
  | Inert
```

Comment: Excellent, that is clearer. The only thing I'd have to change is where the position is held, as I'm using collision.